# Issue with building for Android

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I've incorporated Fabric and Crashlytics in my Unity project and I'm trying to build for Android. The messages I'm getting are:

```
Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
-bootclasspath "/Users/mihai.stan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-24/android.jar" -d "/Users/mihai.stan/Dev/SideScroller/Temp/StagingArea/bin/classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com/tagonsoft/spaceattack/R.java" "io/fabric/answers/android/unity/R.java" "io/fabric/beta/android/unity/R.java" "io/fabric/crashlytics/android/unity/R.java" "io/fabric/sdk/android/unity/R.java" "io/fabric/unity/android/R.java" "io/fabric/unity/crashlytics/android/R.java"
warning: /Users/mihai.stan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-24/android.jar(java/lang/Object.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
warning: /Users/mihai.stan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-24/android.jar(java/lang/AutoCloseable.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
2 warnings

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and

```
    UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
    Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuild

Postprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and

```
Error building Player: UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
```

Keep in mind that I have updated both the jkd and jre and Android Studio.
Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Why not find out what is causing the problem? You can do this by creating a new project then try to build it. If it works, add the plugins one by one and see which one prevents Unity from building for Android.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Tried building an empty project without fabric, worked. Tried to do with Fabric and Crashlytics, failed, same error as the one posted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I had updated the jdk, however Unity failed to detect the new path automatically, so I had to do it by hand. Everything works as intended now.